mergeE gremlin type script
g.mergeE(
                new Map([
                  [T.label, edgeLabel],
                  [Direction.out, `src_${id}`],
                  [Direction.in, `dest_${id}`],
                ]),
              )
              .option(
                onCreate,
                new Map([
                  ['created', Date.now()],
                  ['weight', weight],
                ]),
              )
              .option(
                onMatch,
                new Map([
                  ['updated', Date.now()],
                  ['weight', __.values('weight').math('_ + ' + weight)], // Increment weight using math
                ]),
              )
              .elementMap()
              .toList()
              .then((data) => console.log(data))

Im trying to run this mergeE in type script, and keep getting errors. Is there a way to get the value of existing edge property(if exist the property always exist) and use it for the calculation of the new value of it
